# What is the diffrence between pass by reference and dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation

I just want to know about the difference between above two.Is there something called dynamic memory allocation because of pass by reference feature by pointers?

Comment: Your question does not make sense, as the two things have nothing to do with each other. They're completely orthogonal.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, since these operations aren’t at all similar. One is allocating memory, one is passing information somewhere else. It’s like the difference between buying a book and telling a friend there’s a book on the shelf.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I just want to know those are similar or there are dependent for each other or different or not dependent with each other?

Answer (score 1):

Those two are two different things.

In C++, **pass by reference** is done by adding `&` to the parameter in a function:

```
void func(&a) {
   a = 5;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    printf("%d", a);
    func(a);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code will pass the reference of variable `a` to `func()`. This cause the value of variable `a` within the `main()` method to change as well.

**Dynamic memory allocation** is another thing. It is done as follows:

```
int* arr;
arr = new int[n];
```

where `n` will be determined in the runtime. The memory you allocate dynamically as above should be deallocated by yourself to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score -1):

The contrast that you're really interested in  is between pass by reference and pass by pointer.

```
void f(int* ip) {
    ++*ip;
}

void g(int& ir) {
    ++ir;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    f(&i);
    std::cout << i << '\n'; // i is 1
    g(i);
    std::cout << i << '\n'; // i is 2
    return 0;
}
```

Back in the olden days (when we all wrote code in C) there were no references, so if you wanted to be able to create an object, pass it to a function, and have that function modify the object, you had to pass the **address** of that object. Inside the function you dereference the pointer, and that lets you modify the object that was passed in. That's what the function `f` does.

In C++ we have pass by reference. That lets you call the function with the object itself, no need to take the address; and in the function, no need to dereference a pointer. That's what the function `g` does.

Both of these will work for objects that you create on the stack and objects that you create with dynamic allocation, that is, with `new`. The previous version used an object on the stack. Here's one with an object created with `new`:

```
int main() {
    int *ii = new int(0);
    f(ii);
    std::cout << *ii << '\n'; // ii is 1
    g(*ii);
    std::cout << *ii << '\n'; // ii is 2
    delete ii;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget there is also pass by value, which actually makes a difference beyond just being syntactic sugar.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow -- I didn't forget; the question was about references and pointers.